# $location.path takes time to work after bootstrap modal hide (hide.bs.modal) event is fired

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

```
    // show mymodal
    // register an event to route to a different page once modal is closed
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        if ($location.path() == '/') {
            $location.path('/ser/mynewpath');
            alert("fired"); // just to check the event was fired
        }
    });
    // open the modal
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

I'm calling the bootstrap modal #myModal using JavaScript. Once I close the modal I want to direct the page to a different path. The problem is it takes 30sec - 1 min to direct the page after closing the modal. I added an alert to check if the event is getting late to fire, but I get the alert the moment I close the modal, but the page is only directed after a long wait.

Sometimes when I click somewhere else it will get fired. But this is not happening always - at times the long wait is inevitable.

My initial guess was since I'm using the bootstrap modal and using the $location, angular might not detect it the moment modal gets closed. But now it seems like a dumb guess. I also tried changing the event trigger to 'hidden.bs.modal' but got the same result.

I will try adding angular $modal and see if this solves, will post the updates. But meanwhile I'm thrilled to understand the cause behind this delay in this setup.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is `jquery` event `angular` will not be aware of this event immediately. It will have to wait till the next digest cycle and that is causing the delay. You try using `$scope.$apply`

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
        if ($location.path() == '/') {
            $location.path('/ser/mynewpath');
            alert("fired"); // just to check the event was fired
        }
}
```